# jquery easyui datagrid pagination not working with appendRow

Tags: jquery, datagrid, pagination, jquery-easyui

I'm using jeasyui datagrid, and I'm using pagination for quite long time now, but currently requirement as such I have to add data of form upon form "Add Data" button clicked. Every thing is working perfect, its just pagination which aint working with appendRow.

[image]

And below is code I have used. Please help out, if someone out there had faced same issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/js/jquery.datagrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/datagrid-filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src= "/js/datagrid-bufferview.js"></script>

<form id="MyUpload" method="post" name="MyUpload"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<portlet:actionURL/>">
 <!--some code -->
 <table> 
     <tr>
        <td>
           <div align="right">Name</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div align="right" width="180px">Branch</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div align="right" width="180px">Order No:</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="orderNo" id="orderNo" type="text"/> 
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" colspan="2">
         <a id="addId" onclick="HandleBrowseClick();">Add</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
 <table>
    <table>
    <div>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0 0 0; border-bottom: none;" class="gridTbl">
            <div class="easyui-panel" title="Upload details">
                <table id="dg" class="tt" style="width: 980px;"
                    data-options="
                                    singleSelect:true,
                                    rownumbers:true,
                                    reload:true,
                                    pagination:true,
                                    view:bufferview,
                                    pageSize:10
                            ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-options="field:'name',width:100">Name </th>
                            <th data-options="field:'branch',width:100">Branch</th>
                            <th data-options="field:'orderNo',width:100">Order No</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </tr>
</table>


</form>

function HandleBrowseClick() {

        var name = $("#name").val();                            
        var branch= $('#branch').val();
        var orderNo = $('#orderNo').val();

        $('#dg').datagrid('appendRow', {
            name    : name,
            branch  : branch,
            orderNo : orderNo
        });
}
```

Thanks,
Inayath

Answer (score 0):

You should use yoour values in quotes like this:

```
 $('#dg').datagrid('appendRow', {
        name        : "name",
        branch      : "branch"
    });
```

check documentation here: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php#usage

Comment: Thanks for quick response Soyaslan, I know if its value, its has to be within quotes, but I'm assigning variables so quotes not required.

Comment: So can you show some more code? Where the variables come  from? how are you calling this adder function?